# `<path>` being surrounded with quotes when sending to `<SvgIcon>`, causing SVG to not render

Tags: javascript, svg, material-ui, storybook

When attempting to use Material-UI's `SvgIcon` component the `<path>` is being surrounded by quotes, causing the SVG to not render.

[image]

I am working out of Storybook in an MDX file. To render the SVG I've tried a few methods, but they all result in the same output. The most straightforward of these attempts is:

```js
import { accessibility1Icon } from '@cds/core/icon';

export const Template = (args) => {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...args}>{accessibility1Icon[1].outline}</SvgIcon>
  )
}
```

The reference going into `<SvgIcon>` is indeed a `path`. It does come out (as seen in the image above) but it is surrounded in quotes in the DOM.

What might I be missing that is causing these quotes, or what can be done to retype the reference so they don't appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot render a `string` as `JSX`,
You have to find a way to convert the `string` to `JSX`.

**1-** A solution using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
import { accessibility1Icon } from '@cds/core/icon';

export const Template = (args) => {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...args}>
      <g dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: accessibility1Icon[1].outline }} />
    </SvgIcon>
  )
}
```

**2-** A solution using [`html-react-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)

```
import { accessibility1Icon } from '@cds/core/icon';
import parse  from 'html-react-parser';

export const Template = (args) => {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...args}>
     {parse(accessibility1Icon[1].outline)}
    </SvgIcon>
  )
}
```